# What's the big deal with unicode?

Tags: unicode

I've heard a lot of people talk about how some new version of a language now supports unicode, and how much of an achievement unicode is.  What's the big deal about being able to support a new characterset.  It seems like something which would rarely if ever be used but people mention it quite often.  What's the benefit or reason people use or even care about unicode?

Comment: "rarely used"? Way to dismiss more than half of the world population!

Comment: @Alex, to be fair most of the world was able to use computers before Unicode was invented - it was just awkward.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Well, I certainly don't miss pre-Unicode days of Russian internet. Unicode *is* a big deal.

Comment: Even before unicode there were [many different "code pages"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) that [generally] mapped different alphabets to a single byte. Instead of just dealing with one symbol-space (unicode) and a few common encodings (UTF-8, UTF-16), one had to deal with N code pages and different encodings based on localization! Ick!

Comment: World wars, smallpox, and non-universal character encodings should all be left in the 20th century where they belong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Programming languages are used to produce *software*.

Software is used to solve *problems* faced by *humans*.

Producing software has a *cost*.

Software that solves problems for humans produces *value*. This value can be expressed in the form of *profit*, or the reduction of *costs*, depending on the *business model* of the software developer. How the value is expressed is irrelevant for the purposes of this discussion; what is relevant is that *net value* is produced.

There are seven billion humans in the world. A significant fraction of them are most comfortable reading text that is not written in the Latin alphabet.

Software which purports to solve a problem for some fraction of those seven billion humans who do not use the Latin alphabet does so more effectively if developers can easily manipulate text written in non-Latin alphabets.

Therefore, a programming language which supports non-Latin character sets lowers the *costs* of software developers, thereby enabling them to solve more problems for more people at lower costs, and thereby produce more value.

Unicode is the de facto standard for manipulation of non-Latin text.

Therefore, Unicode is important to the design and implementation of programming languages.

**Our goal as programming language designers is the creation of tools which produce maximum value. Supporting Unicode is an easy way to massively increase the scope and range of real human problems that can be solved in software.**

Comment: Conclusive proof that Eric is just a fancy Prolog bot.

Comment: @Eric: This might be a stupid question but how can you tell if an app needs unicode? If you have written a tool that manages an application's shortcut keys, so need to be able to show the user what keys they are pressing, etc, would this tool need unicode? Or is this about localization? Or is this about things like textbox controls, etc to set some data like object names, where the user might type a name in any language so potentially could be Chinese, Japanese, etc? If so, wouldn't .NET take care of this for me? I don't think I dealt with this before.

Comment: @Joan: All of the above. In C#, and in Windows in general, strings are (almost) always in Unicode, so you've dealt with Unicode strings every day for probably quite a long time now without realizing it.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric, so these are abstracted from me then? I never had to think about handling non-Latin characters myself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Eric.  The primary application I work on is used all throughout the world but my programming language (as far as I know) doesn't support Unicode (Delphi).  Apparently newer versions do support unicode and I was wondering why it was such a driving factor in a reason to upgrade.  Looks like it may be time to upgrade my IDE and (hopefully) get in on some of this unicode to help my users.

Comment: @Joan: There's no free lunch; you do have to give this some thought. For example, suppose you are comparing two strings to sort them into "alphabetical" order. *Whose alphabetical order?* Different cultures around the world sort things into different orders. For example, the German character ß is a fancy way to write "ss".  Even though it is one Unicode character, when it appears in a string it should be *sorted* as though the string contains "ss". That's why String.Compare takes a CultureInfo as its argument, so that you can say whose rules you want to use.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. I see what you mean now. I never used those CultureInfo stuff before, but heard about them, so I guess I will pay more attention to it in some cases. But for work, I don't think they want us to do those because everybody is using English version of Windows. That's my understanding at least, but then again I don't work on enterprise apps, just in-house tools.

Comment: @Joan: Note that C# supports Unicode throughout the language. If you're a Greek programmer it is perfectly legal for you to say "string Σώκρατες = null;" if you like naming your variables after dead philosophers.  (And notice of course that StackOverflow, written largely in C#, is handling the Unicode text in these comments just fine.)

Comment: @Eric: Thanks Eric. I didn't know that. I never saw non-Latin C# code myself. Glad that all code I have seen was using English words even with foreign comments. But lastly if you were to look for a substring inside another string, if the user types in Chinese or Greek, etc, C#'s string.IndexOf would find it correctly without a cultureinfo, right?

Comment: Too bad there isn't a C# compiler for the Αντικύθηρα so the Greek programmers could have dead philosophers on ancient computers.

Comment: @Joan: Suppose you ask for the index of "ss" in "Fuß". The correct answer if you are a German speaker is that sure, the substring is there. That's why there is a version of IndexOf that takes an enumeration that lets you specify whether the indexing operation is by "ordinal", ie, match exactly the Unicode characters, or by using culture-sensitive rules. So again, you have to think about it carefully. When you use IndexOf, think about whether the strings you're searching need to be exact matches of the precise characters, or whether they should be sensitive to the culture that produced them.

Comment: Furthermore, C# having its source code in any valid encoding of Unicode allows me to write such humorous code as:
if (ಠ_ಠ == null) continue;
and have it compile correctly. :)

Comment: @Eric: Don't forget about language-specific casing rules.  What's a capital `i`?  In most languages, it's `I`, but in Turkish it's `İ`.

Answer (score 4):

In the beginning, there were 256 possible characters and many different Code pages to represent them. It became a tangled mess. Supporting multiple languages and multiple characters sets became a programmer's nightmare.

Then the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/) was formed. It created a standard that would allow a single character set with 256 x 256 = 65536 characters (plus combinations thereof) to include almost all languages of the world.

The biggest advantage is that a single character string may contain multiple languages. That is no small thing.

Unicode is now the native character specification used in Windows ever since Windows 2000. it is also allowed as a character set in HTML and on websites.

If your application does not support Unicode, or is not planning to support it, then it is only a matter of time until your application will be left behind.

Comment: 'left behind' is a bit of an overstatement. Apps which don't need to display text to a user have absolutely no use for unicode. (Think embedded software, systems level stuff, etc)

Comment: @Darron: Apps which "don't need to display text to a user" probably make up less than 1% of all apps.

Comment: Err, seriously? Take a look around. Within an 8' square space I've got a network switch, cd-drive, hard drives, mice, trackpad probably has a microcontroller, fingerprint reader, probably 4-20 other subsystems within my laptop I'm not thinking of... benchtop power supply, older wired phone, digital watch, webcam, usb hard drive enclosure, etc.  I'm not even touching systems level stuff...  like various services and daemons running on the pc, etc.  Oh... and baseband and wireless modules in my cellphone, maybe the sim card, another camera module...  smart cards in my wallet...

Comment: ... And unicode isn't simply 16 bits. Encoding matters, too. Windows may be UTF-16, but web pages are typically UTF8, as is Linux, etc. There's also UTF-32.

Comment: ... last thing. Unicode as the native charset in Windows is from Windows NT, much earlier than Win2K.

Comment: @darron: The person who wrote the software for those embedded devices might not have been a native reader of the Latin alphabet. The advantages incurred when programming languages can manipulate Unicode apply to the entire software tool chain, from editors to debuggers to emulators. Regardless of whether the software actually produced manipulates human-readable text in any form, the people who *produce* the software surely do. Unicode support in languages and tool chains helps those people.

Comment: @darron: Those apps didn't need to display single-byte encodings either.

Comment: @Ikessler The symbol-space of unicode is larger than 65k. (Hence the need for surrogate pairs in UTF-16 :-)

Comment: @eric lippert: Yes, but that's entirely different than saying the application itself must support unicode or its going to die. I'm certainly much happier with UTF8 than the old charset nightmare.  However, I take exception to people making blanket statements about software in general with an obviously limited point of view.

Comment: @dan04: Yes, but the statement was not "if your text-displaying application does not support Unicode...", it was more general than that. It's the generality I have a problem with.

Comment: In the beginning there were just 127 characters. And a parity bit. Don't underestimate that, I think some protocols (including SMTP) are still officially 7 bit.

Comment: Right.  That's why non-ASCII e-mails have to resort to hacks like quoted-printable.

Comment: Unicode has had more than 64K codepoints defined (though not necessarily assigned) since Unicode 2.0 (in July 1996). The number of encoded characters surpassed 64K in Unicode 3.1 (March 2001).

Answer (score 3):

> What's the big deal about being able
>   to support a new characterset.

Unicode is not just "a new characterset".  It's the character set that removes the need to think about character sets.

How would you rather write a string containing the Euro sign?

- `"\x80"`, `"\x88"`, `"\x9c"`, `"\x9f"`, `"\xa2\xe3"`, `"\xa2\xe6"`, `"\xa3\xe1"`, `"\xa4"`, `"\xa9\xa1"`, `"\xd9\xe6"`, `"\xdb"`, or `"\xff"` depending upon the encoding.
- `"\u20AC"`, in every locale, on every OS.

Comment: This is confusing *encoding* with *code page/symbol space*, I believe. Not that I disagree with the conclusion :)

Comment: Well, prior to Unicode, there wasn't really a clear distinction between the concepts of "coded character set" and "character encoding".

Answer (score 2):

Unicode can support pretty much any language in the world. Without such an encoding you would have to worry about choosing the correct encoding for different languages, which is very bothersome (not to mention mixing multiple languages in the same text block, ugh)

Unicode support in a language means that the language's native character/string type supports all those languages as well, without the user having to worry about character encodings or multibyte characters and such while doing computations. Of course, one still has to acnowledge character encodings when doing I/O, but doing your string processing in one single sensible encoding helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you care anything about internationalization (AKA the rest of the world) scientific notations, etc you would care about unicode.  Unicode is difficult to deal with because we have been so ingrained just ASCII support. But now that modern systems support Unicode, there is no reason really not to just encode your things UTF-8.  I know I work in publishing and for a long time we had to do hack things like insert gif images of formulas etc.  Now we can put unicode straight in and people can search and copy and paste etc, and our code can deal with it by using unicode regexes etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to communicate with someone whose native language is not English (either the British or American variants), you care. A lot.

Comment: Even British English also requires non-ASCII chars - the pound sign requires the Win1252 ("extended ANSI" I used to know it as) charset.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone says - support for all the charactersets and formatting used by every other language and locale in the world. Open source and commercial developers both like that because it increases their potential user base by about 20x fold (and growing).

Answer (score 1):

Unicode is a good thing because it eliminates character set problems and leaves one less thing to worry about. Even if your software never leaves the U.S., you never know when you're going to run into a filename or text field with an odd character in it, and Unicode lets you live in ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Americans like Daisetsu may not care about Unicode, but the rest of the world uses a bit more than 26 Latin letters, and there Unicode is heavily used.

We had hundreds of messed up charsets in the past solely because American computer scientists thought "why would anyone want to use more than 26 Latin characters like we have in English?"

Narrow-mindedness is a bad thing.

Comment: as an American living in Japan who regularly deals with multibyte and Unicode, let's say "People like Daisetsu".  Yes, there may be many Americans like him, but I assure you we can find narrow-minded thinking in whichever country you'd like to pick.  Also - the reason for charset limitations in the past isn't narrow-minded scientists: memory limitations were the main initial causes.